# homotopy type of loop space components

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a closed manifold, and let $X^{S^1}$ denote the *free loop space* of $X$, that is, the set of continuous maps $S^1 \rightarrow X$. Let $Y$ denote a component of $X^{S^1}$.

What conditions ensure that $Y$ is homotopic to a finite CW complex? (by finite, I mean, the total number of cells is finite).

*Edit* - thanks to Somnath, sufficient conditions are certainly when $X$ is an Eilenberg-Maclane space, as then the based loop space is contractible. Are there any other different sufficient conditions?

Comment: If the total number of cells in a CW complex is finite, then the space it locally compact, but in general $Y$ is not locally compact.

Comment: (you will have more luck if you look for finite CW complexes with the homotopy type of $Y$)

Comment: It's true for some manifolds, right? Like say, $X=S^1$?

Comment: @ Ricardo - It's true for $S^1$ since it's an example of a $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$-space. More generally, take $X$ to be a hyperbolic $3$-manifold or a surface of non-zero genus. These are all $K(\pi_1(X),1)$'s. Why is this relevant? Because $X^{S^1}$ fibres over $X$ with fibre $\Omega X$, the based loop space. The connected components of $X^{S^1}$ are labelled by $\pi_1(X)$. For such an $X$, $\Omega X$ has the homotopy type of $\pi_1(X)$, which is discrete. Hence, $X^{S^1}$ looks like a collection of covering spaces of $X$. If all the covers are finite and $C_\ast(X)$ is finite, then you're done!

Comment: Are you saying that the components (different from the one containing the constant map) of $(S^1)^(S^1)$, the space of all maps $S^1\to S^1$, are finite CW-complexes?

Comment: @Somnath: shouldn't path components be labelled by conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(X)$ (of course this makes no difference in the circle case). Also, could you elaborate on your second last sentence?
@Ricardo: They are certainly homotopy equivalent to finite CW-complexes, since they are contractible. But asking for a CW-structure *on the nose* with finitely many cells may be a bit too strong, as Mariano suggests.

Comment: For a path connected space the loopspace has one component for each conjugacy of the fundamental group of $X$, and the fundamental group of each component is the centralizer of a representative for that conjugacy class. In the cases that Somnath mentioned, these subgroups have infinite index but the corresponding noncompact covering space often has the homotopy type of a finite complex (such as a circle) anyway.

Comment: @ Mark - Yes that's what I meant to write down - conjugacy classes of $\pi_1(X)$. As for the second comment, the free loop space $X^{S^1}$ is a fibre bundle over $X$ with fibre $\Omega X$. For homotopy considerations (if $X$ is a $K(\pi,1)$) this is as good as a fibre bundle over $X$ with fibre $\pi$. But this is just the notion of covering spaces. 

Comment: @ Mark, Mariano: I edited the question to be more meaningful, now we are only asking for the homotopy type of a finite CW complex.

Answer (score 8):

There are some negative results about. For instance, a theorem of [Sullivan and Vigué-Poirrier](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214433729) states that if $M$ is a closed manifold with $\pi_1(M)$ finite, and if the cohomology *algebra* $H^*(M;\mathbb{R})$ requires at least two generators, then the Betti numbers of $M^{S^1}$ are unbounded. The finiteness assumption implies that $M^{S^1}$ has only finitely many path components, and so at least one of them is not a finite CW-complex.

Comment: Even in the case when $M$ is simply connected and $H^\ast(M;\mathbb{R})$ is monogenic, the Betti numbers of $M^{S^1}$ are bounded but the sum is unbounded. Of course, in this case no such $Y$ as the OP asked exists since $M^{S^1}$ is connected.

Comment: This is true. Whenever $M$ is a simply-connected, non-contractible manifold, the loop space $M^{S^1}$ is not homotopy equivalent to a finite complex (since it has infinite Lusternik-Schnirelmann category).